# how to change the background color of one textview contained inside my costumizable listview, according to the record status

Tags: android, listview, colors, background, textview

when populating or when drawing my costumizable listview, i want to be able to change the backgound color on one textview contained inside each listviewitem, according to the record status... someting like this:

```
for (each item in listviewitem) {
  switch (item.status) {
    case 0: textview_in_listviewitem.background = black;
    case 1: textview_in_listviewitem.background = red;
    case 2: textview_in_listviewitem.background = blue;
    case 3: textview_in_listviewitem.background = green;
    case 4: textview_in_listviewitem.background = yellow;
    case 5: textview_in_listviewitem.background = orange;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to create a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try fetching the `TextView` using the `findViewById()`.

Something like this (say the `id` of the `TextView` you want to fetch is `tvid`):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvid);
```

You can then go about doing anything you want with it.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: my problem is how to fetch one single textview inside one listview with several textviews one each listviewitem, so that when populating my adapter with data that i've retrieved from my webservice, make the textcolor or background color of that textview change to red because that record/listviewitem data was canceled, or change it to green because the record/listviewitem data was delivered

Comment: So to populate the listview you must have made a row view?